# for arbitrary vector $v,u$, is there the matrix X which satisfy the relation exp$[X]\,v=u$?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

Nowadays, I'm studying for exponential map of Lie group.

my question is, To make the form of exp$\begin{pmatrix}x_{11}&x_{12}&\cdots \\x_{21}&\ddots \\ \vdots\end{pmatrix}$,

I have to multiply same matrixes. so I wonder more basically,
when the matrix $A$ which has all component can be arbitrary number, although we make $A^N$,whether $A^N$ has also all component which can be arbitrary number or not.

additionally, My major is physics, by the way, I almost don't know about
mathematic symbols. If you know the process of proof, please 
show me the proof without mathematic symbols possible.

Comment: Its not clear to me what you are asking. What do you mean by "$A^N$ also has all component which can be arbitrary or not"? The components of $A^N$ clearly depend on what the components of $A$ are.

Comment: Also how is the actual content of your question related to the question title?

Comment: because the exponential map of $GL(n,\mathcal{C})$ is made by 
\lim_{N\to \infty}[exp$\begin{pmatrix}
x_{11}/N&x_{12}/N&\cdots
\\
x_{21}/N&\ddots
\end{pmatrix}$]^N.

so, I think most general exponential map of Lie group
can make all vector for fixed vector which is multiplied to exponential map.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your question.

Comment: me too!! thank you for your interest!!